# how to use --s3-secret option with knife ec2?

Tags: amazon-s3, chef-infra, knife

When using

```
knife ec2 server create ... --s3-secret s3://bucket/path/to/key
```

I get an Argument Error from chef-client of "No secret specified". How do I configure knife to recognize the s3 path? I've placed the keys and region in my knife.rb file (and also configured AWSCLI for the user).

using the *--secret-file* parameter with a local path is working fine and the AWS ID and Secret Key are recognized as I do not have to pass them in the command, so what is missing?

Comment: run `chef-client --log_level debug` and paste the output. also try to verify whether you have an access to `s3://bucket/path/to/key` using the aws secret and access keys specified in your `knife.rb`.

Comment: Here is a link to the output. There is no log level option for knife ec2 so I ran in -VV mode as well as normally. I was able to run an "aws s3 cp" command from my workstation and copy the key. http://www.mediafire.com/download/9ff84ze50cs9yzx/chef-client_s3-secret

Comment: set the aliasing to the key by utilizing the [`knife[:secret_file]`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html) attribute over `knife.rb`, rather than utilize the `--s3-secret` (maybe there is a bug). note that the key in question, is the key that is used for [data bag item encryption\decryption](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#knife-title-options).

Comment: I tried that too, and it is working. It seems to be a good solution for now although I'd like to eventually grab it from a bucket. Thanks for your help.

Comment: great! i will convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the aliasing to the key by utilizing the [`knife[:secret_file]`](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#knife-title-options) attribute over `knife.rb`, rather than utilize the `--s3-secret` (maybe there is a bug). note that the key in question, is the key that is used [for data bag item encryption\decryption](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#knife-title-options)